# Xamarin Android Plugging in USB Barcode causes the app to restart

Tags: android, xamarin, usb, barcode-scanner

Weird one, but we have an android app written in xamarin forms. When we plugin a USB Barcode scanner via a USB-C hub it causes the app to restart (also when you unplug it will restart as well). Just wondering if anyone knows the cause of this and how to fix?

Comment: search `android app dev plugging in usb device causes app restart` for related discussions. You should be able to translate any java/kotlin fix to c# for xamarin.